# Server 2003 to 2008 Migration My Docs problems

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, migration

I have a school with about 100 teachers and a complex situation.  Every year the teachers turn in their laptops for 1 week for maintenance.  After that we send them back out so they can prepare for next year over the summer.  After this happened My co-worker did a Server 2k3 to 2k8 migration and then left the company.  Everything seemed fine then we noticed that any teacher that opened a document in their My Docs folder (which was on the 2k3) offsite, prior to the migration those files will not sync to the 2008 server.  However as long as they opened their documents after the migration to the 2008 server they sync just fine.  It seems that as long as the laptop was on the network to get the GP updating the My Documents redirection any file opened after that syncs fine.  I hope this makes sense, if I need to clarify please let me know.  Now for my question, how can I get the few files per teacher that were opened while they were still on the 2k3 server moved over to the 2k8 server without having to go to each computer?  I can verify that the My Documents redirection works just not on those few files.

Thanks
Msindle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try checking the group policy modelling results for that user and see if their folder redirection settings are, in fact, being applied.

It seems strange that *some files* are not being redirected to the right server, given that folder redirection works on a per-folder basis, not per-file